# Dmesg output in linux kernel from char device module

Tags: arrays, string, linux-kernel, output, echo

I'm trying to implement a char device driver in Linux driver. When I try to echo strings into my driver, the result is very weird.

My code to store the strings I input:

```c
int max_size = 1;
char store[1] = {0};
char message[100] = {0};
ssize_t hello_write(struct *filep, const char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *position)

{
  if(length> max_size)
     length = max_size;
  if(copy_from_user(message, buffer, length))
     return -EFAULT;
  strncpy(store, message, max_size);
  printk(KERN_INFO "Actually stored in kernel:%s", store);
  return max_size;
}
ssize_t hello_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *postion)
{
  int error_count = 0;
  error_count = copy_to_user(buffer, store, max_size);
  if(error==0){
    printk(KERN_INFO "read message from kernel: %s", store);
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    printk(KERN_INFO "failed to send %d chars to user", error_count);
    return -EFAULT;
  }
}
```

Test:

> ```
> echo ginger > /dev/test
> cat /dev/test
> ```

I intend to store only the first letter of each input string, anything with the function `strncpy`?

[image: store the string one by one]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value returned by `write` syscall is interpreted as **number of bytes processed**.

Like other standard output utilities `echo` calls `write()` syscall *repeatedly* until it processes **all input bytes**.

So, when you want to store only single byte of the input, you need to return input's full length for mark it as processed.

More correct implementation of `.write` would be:

```c
ssize_t hello_write(struct *filep, const char * __user buffer, size_t length, loff_t *position)
{
  if((*position == 0) && (length > 0)) {
    // Store the first byte of the first input string.
    if(copy_from_user(message, buffer, 1))
       return -EFAULT;
    strncpy(store, message, 1);
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO "Actually stored in kernel:%s", store);
  // But mark the whole string as processed
  *position += length;
  return length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind advice, I realised I forgot to relocate the pointer. Now it works pretty well. Thanks again!